# Is there a circuit like a flip flop but with 1 input and 4 outputs

Tags: digital-logic

I've searched online and can't find anything other than sequential circuits but I'm an amateur just trying to do my thing and don't understand anything. I need a circuit with lets say inputs X and outputs A B C and D when I push a button to pulse X, it will activate A. When I push it again it will activate B and deactivate A. So on and so forth. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Look at a cmos 4017

Comment: Multiplexer aka MUX could be the one you are searching for.

Comment: What power supply does this circuit need to run off of?  Also, how do you plan to debounce the button?

Comment: Try googling ["ring counter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter).

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a *shift register*.  You shift a 1 into the first bit, then 0 after that.

However, there is a big gotcha with what you describe.  Switches bounce.  Your pushbutton may actually go thru dozens of on/off transitions during the first few ms of either edge.

Since you really need to do debouncing too, what you want is most easily handled in a microcontroller.  It can do the debouncing, then activate multiple outputs in any way you choose based on debounced switch transistions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 simple things to achieve this.

1. A 1:4 demultiplexer
2. A mod 4 counter going from 00 to 11, i.e, from 0 to 3.

Connect the select lines of the demultiplexer to the counter.

The output of the counter will be guide the demultiplexer to choose the right path and hence, get the required output

Quick edit: For switch debouncing, the most simple implementation is to use an SR swtich debouncer. A useful source is-
http://www.ee.nmt.edu/~elosery/fall_2008/ee231L/lab6.pdf